# Laptop left on Emirates flight

Tags: emirates, lost-luggage

On Wednesday, May 17, 2017, I left my laptop in back seat pocket of EK419 Business Class. I boarded In Auckland, and deplaned In Sydney. That flight continued on to Dubai, with a stopover in Bangkok. At some point, my laptop would have been found (by cleaning staff either Sydney, Bangkok or Dubai), or by a passenger who would have hopefully handed it in.

I'm finding it incredibly hard to make enquiries about this, being told by Emirates to contact Sydney airport, then the airport telling me to contact Emirates Sydney, and them telling me to contact Emirates Dubai. I can't fill out the online form at Emirates Dubai, as it is assuming I've lost something at the airport, and is asking for terminal details etc which I cannot leave blank if I want to lodge my request. I tried calling +97142245555 (number on website), but no one answers.

I don't think too many laptops would have been left on that particular flight number in Business Class, and it must be somewhere. What else can I do?

Comment: Have you tried twitter? Fb?

Answer (score 2):

It's horrible to leave your laptop on board, and your experiences so far have been very frustrating.  I'm sorry to hear it and hope you get your laptop back.

Emirates' web site lists the following phone number for lost & found in Sydney: +61 2 9667 9111.  Try calling them first.  You could also try phoning Emirates in Sydney at +61 1300 303 777 and see if you can reach someone who can help.  You might try calling during normal business hours in Sydney, or around 4:30 PM (when the flight you took is scheduled to land), although I see EK has flights into and out of SYD at 6 AM, 7 AM, 9 PM, and 10 PM.

If you can't reach anyone, try calling EK main contact number in Dubai and ask the agent, or ask for customer relations.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my first hand experience (although not at these airports or this airline but still) items left on airplanes are found by what they call ground handling companies. So you need to find the relevant ones. This is a PITA.

dnata is part of the Emirates group so it stands to reason they are their ground handlers:

[Sydney](http://www.handbook.aero/hb_handlerpage.html?recnum=126731)  +61 2 9352 7950 
[Dubai](http://www.handbook.aero/hb_handlerpage.html?recnum=7064)  +971 4 216 2636

I can't find theirs at BKK but I would guess it's either [Thai ground services](http://www.airlineupdate.com/content_subscription/gha/company-contacts/thaigroundsvcs.htm) +66 2 137 161 or [Bangkok Flight services](https://www.bangkokflightservices.com/home/contact-bfs/) +66 (0) 2131 5000